# Can't access SMB shares on Windows but can on Linux

Tags: linux, windows, samba, server-message-block, cifs

I've been having some problems with a Samba share that I recently set up.

The share's configuration is as follows:

```
[data]
path = /media/data
available = yes
valid users = admin
read only = no
browseable = yes
public = yes
writable = yes
```

I have been able to access the share on both Linux and OS X through `smbclient`, but on Windows I get a "cannot access" error (0x80070002, system cannot find the file specified). 
The syntax I'm using on Windows is `\\<server-ip>\data`, but `\\<server-ip>\media\data` doesn't work either.

**Update:** I managed to compile Samba on Windows via Cygwin and got `smbclient` working under it, but I still cannot connect to the share through the native client on Windows.

**Update 2:** Partial breakthrough! The problem was with a registry key, `ProviderOrder`, used by Windows to determine which SMB client to use. Mine had been slightly changed by a previous experiment with NFS. To fix it, I set `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order\ProviderOrder` to the following: `vmhgfs,hgfs,LanmanWorkstation,RDPNP`. That got me as far as the login prompt, after which I got another error, 0x800704cf.

**Update 3:** Success! The component at fault here was my adapter's 'Client for Microsoft Networks' package. Once installed, all I had to do was reset the adapter and my share connected seamlessly.

Comment: I have this same issue w/ a question open currently.  You may want to look through the comments to see if you find help.  Mainly, did you add rules to iptables to allow a connection on port 455 and optionally 137,138,and 139?  Link to my question: http://serverfault.com/questions/620502/samba-smbd-on-centos-6-5?noredirect=1#comment744120_620502

Comment: I don't think I'm having problems with iptables, as I can get external clients to connect. Running `nmap` shows that I have open services on ports 139 and 445, as expected for SMB. Thank you very much for the suggestion, though. I'll forward any solutions that come my way.

Comment: @Satalink you might want to check Update 2 above. I'm not sure if it's related to your problem, but it's gotten me one step closer to fixing mine. Best of luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem.

There were two components at fault: the `ProviderOrder` registry key, and a missing adapter package.

### Fault One:

SMB on Windows looks at the `ProviderOrder` registry key under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\NetworkProvider\Order\` to determine which implementation of SMB/CIFS to use. If there is no implementation or an incorrect one listed, Windows gives up. To fix it, simply append this string to the one already in `ProviderOrder`: `mhgfs,hgfs,LanmanWorkstation,RDPNP`.

### Fault Two:

In my case, it seems that my adapter simply came with the 'Client for Microsoft Networks' disabled for some reason or another. To enable it on any adapter, go to the Network and Sharing Center, click 'Change Adapter Settings,' and right click to 'Properties' on your active adapter. From there, select 'Install...', and select 'Add...' on 'Client.' Simply select the 'Client for Microsoft Networks' from the window that appears and click OK. Then, reset your adapter or reboot.

Comment: I added mhgfs, hgfs to ProviderOrder.  "Client for Microsoft Networks" was already added to my adaptor settings.  Mine is still not working.  Glad to hear yours is working though.

Answer (score 1):

The correct path is \\data. The admin user is added in the Linux and Samba? In the Samba, use the binary smbpasswd  to add the user.

Comment: Yes, the admin user is added correctly in both, with the password set. I tried disabling NetBIOS (on the theory that it was interfering), but nothing changed.

Comment: How's the selinux configured? I'm not an expert, so I usually disable in file servers. The command is setenforce 0 and the permanent conf is in /etc/sysconfig/selinux (I guess, can't confirm right now)

Comment: It isn't. I'm running a plain Linux kernel, with no SELinux. I just noticed this, however: `smbstatus` gives me the error `NT_STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED`. Don't know what that means, though.

Comment: It's revoking the authentication. Try an 777 permission mode, may be that (shooting everywheeverywhere haha)

Comment: Just tried that. No change. On the other hand, running `smbstatus` as root got rid of the error. This is really confounding me...

Comment: The pdbedit -L shows the admin user? What's the return from the testparm command?

Comment: I don't have pbdedit on my system, but I'm certain that the admin user exists both as a user and in samba's database. testparm doesn't return any errors in the configuration.

Comment: You are not running a distro, right? Never did that, just distros... Is that a vm? Can you export as an OVF upload somewhere?

Comment: I'm running freshly installed Arch. I followed their install guide for Samba. Like I said, the share works perfectly fine on Linux and OS X clients. It's only on Windows that it doesn't connect.

Comment: There's some configurarion in Conncetions and Shares in the Windows, try to change something there (don't have a Windows box here to tell you certanly). Also, try to turn off the Win FW..

Comment: Nothing in the network configuration seemed pertinent aside from NetBIOS over TCP/IP, which I disabled. My firewall is disabled.

Comment: I'm gonna make a test here and report to you!

Comment: Running `smbpasswd -a user` is crucial here!

Answer (score 0):

I have read that you need to include these directives to your conf for windows to work.

```
hosts allow = 127.0. x.x.x.x etc
hosts deny = 0.0.0.0/0
```

I am having a similar issue, but haven't resolved it yet.

Comment: Tried this, no change. Thanks for the suggestion, though.